# Command-line application using setuptools and Anaconda Python

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools

I have a Python command line application that I have been distributing on PyPI in the manner described here: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

In short, that means I'm using setuptools with the entry_points option in my setup.py file:

```
import programs    

setup(
    name='my_package',
    entry_points={
        'gui_scripts': [
                'program1 = programs.program1:main',...
        ]
    })
```

My package is uploaded to PyPI, and can be installed using pip.  Normal behavior on the command line is that `program1` launches the GUI.

The problem is, I would like to support the Anaconda distribution of Python.  If I pip install and try to run `program1` using using Anaconda, I get this warning:

```
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

The executable script lives here:

```
~/anaconda2/bin/program1
```

And here is its text:

```
#!/Users/***/anaconda2/bin/python                                            

import re
import sys

from programs.program1 import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

And it is importing program1 from this location:

```
/Users/***/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/programs/program1.pyc
```

How can I get program_1 to run as an executable using Anaconda?